# What configuration for DSN access in Apache?

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, odbc, dsn

I am configuring a standalone Apache Http Server (2.2.16, on Windows. Can be XP or more recent) to communicate with [J](http://www.jsoftware.com) (standalone as in not XAMPP or other packages). I can get my list of user DSN's in J normally, but not when coming in through Apache.

I installed PHP, tried a connection with odbc_connect, no dice. odbc_data_source requires an active connection (even if odbc32.dll sqlitedatasources does not...), and all connections were refused. Furthermore, as a test, I did install XAMPP, and configured it to talk to J. With XAMPP, both J and PHP were able to list the local user DSN's.

So I'm supposing the delta is the standalone Apache Http Server. What modules or settings should I activate in the configuration, to allow third party modules access to user DSN's?

Note:

And as to why I can't use XAMPP or others to start with, sigh, it's a long story. Essentially, customers will be public entities, with very controlling IT, that require a list of all components of software solutions. Experience has shown that getting such programs as Apache approved can be testy, and I'd rather not try to redo this approval process with pre-made packages, as practical and awesome as they may be.

Comment: Also, I just moved this question from ServerFault manually. Please don't send it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User DSN's can't be read by Apache when it runs as a service (big 'duh' addressed to myself). Using System DSN's.

EDIT: Better yet: File DSN.